# What does the 'uses' keyword mean in regards to laravel routing?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel and trying my best to RTM but having difficulty understanding a few things.  I think there is an expected level on context that I am not aware of when it comes to routing.  In reviewing [the documentation for routing](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters) I see that the `uses` keyword allows one to `Attach(ing) A Filter To A Controller Action`, but what does that mean?  I have an existing site that is using the `uses` keyword but I am at a loss at to what it is actually doing.  Can someone explain (a tab more thoroughly than the laravel documentation does) and show a very simple example what this actually does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyword `uses` of routing is where you define which action (controller method or anonymous function) will be used to process that particular route. Take this controller method example:

```
Route::get('user', array('uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'));
```

It says that `uses` will call the method `showProfile` in your `UserController` class, this would be the class:

```
class UserController extends Controller {

    public function showProfile 
    {
       return "Hi! I'm the showProfile method!";
    }

}
```

So, if you hit the

```
http://localhost/user
```

You should see the message

```
Hi! I'm the showProfile method!
```

Because your route execute that action you defined in the `uses`.

An anonymous function (closure) example would be:

```
Route::get('user', array('uses' => function() {

    return "Hi, I'm a closure!";

}));
```

Comment: More generally, `uses` denotes what going to this route will 'execute': if its value is a string, it's assumed to be a `Controller@action`-style path, but it could be a closure too. There's actually a bit more logic in there too (for better or worse). For example, if you're using closure, you can ignore the `uses` key and just throw a closure (unkeyed) in the array, and Laravel will still pick it up, so you can do `Route::get('my/route', ['as' => 'my.route', function () { return 'Routed!'; }]);`

Comment: You're right, properly edited to also include closures as an option to be used in `uses`.

Comment: Hmm maybe I should have done that directly. Sorry, didn't think about that.

Answer (score 4):

Antonio's answer answers your (exact) question pretty perfectly, but I figured I'd add my comments to the wider context of the question, as I feel you don't actually want to know what `uses` is for, but instead are generally confused by the way routing works (you mention `uses` is for filters, which it isn't, but its use is a side-effect of adding filter configuration). So allow me to explain:

The router methods are actually kinda simple, but you just need to know what syntax they expect. There are two main forms, the unconfigured and the configured:

Unconfigured:

```
// syntax:
Route::get($route, $action);

// controller method
Route::get('some/route', 'Controller@action');
// closure
Route::get('some/route', function () {
    return View::make(/* etc. */);
});
```

But as soon as you need to add configuration to a given route (including filters, naming, etc.) you need to use a slightly different syntax:

```
// syntax:
Route::get($route, $config); // where $config is an array

// controller method
Route::get('some/route', array(
    'as'   => 'my.route.name',
    'uses' => 'Controller@action',
));

// closure
Route::get('some/route', array(
    'before' => 'some.filter',
    'uses'   => function () {
        return View::make(/* etc. */);
    }
));

// closure alternative
Route::get('some/route', array(
    'before' => 'some.filter',
    function () {
        return View::make(/* etc. */);
    }
));
```

So, as soon as you need to name your route (using `as`) or add a filter (using `before` and `after`) you need to turn that more simple syntax into the slightly more complex array syntax. And when you make it an array, you still need a way to tell Laravel what to actually use for the execution - that's what `uses` is for.