# Use of "uses" in router of Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have written this and it is working.

```
Route::get( 'users', [ 'uses' => 'UsersController@index'] );
```

Now i am removing the "uses" and it is still working.

```
Route::get( 'users', 'UsersController@index' );
```

What is the requirement of "uses" here. Pleas give the view with reference url.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923394/what-does-the-uses-keyword-mean-in-regards-to-laravel-routing

Comment: Thank you. the second answer is really specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the 'uses' keyword mean in regards to laravel routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923394/what-does-the-uses-keyword-mean-in-regards-to-laravel-routing)